# how to search a word with in a column and split the date followed by the word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two column create date and Rtrail

> > example
> >
> > ### Create_date    ------------------------------------      Rtrail
> >
> > > 5/4/2014  6:28:34 PM........................................amin(05/11/14 20:16:19)->dd(05/11/14 21:17:04)

## Output

### Create_date    ------------------------------------      Rtrail

> > > 05/11/14 20:16:19 PM........................................amin(05/11/14 20:16:19)->dd(05/11/14 21:17:04)

Now  i want split datetime which begin with **"**amin**"* and update the previous column "**create date**".
How i do in SQL.Need Suggestion

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Are you wanting to update the create_date? What datatype is create_date?

Comment: I am using SQL Server. Yes i want to update the create date column and data type is datetime

Answer (score 1):

This works on the sample data you provided. It is pretty brittle in this form. I would add some where predicates to check for the existence of ( and ) as well as making sure the value inside there can be cast as a date. I will that part up to you.

```
update #Something
set create_date = SUBSTRING(Rtrail, charindex('(', Rtrail) + 1,  charindex(')', Rtrail) - charindex('(', Rtrail) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some string parsing to pull the date out.  If the Rtrail date will always begin and end with the same characters you can use something like the following query:

```
DECLARE @rtrail VARCHAR(256) = 'amin(05/11/14 20:16:19)->dd(05/11/14 21:17:04)'
    , @startIndex INT
    , @endIndex INT
    , @dateStringLength INT
    , @extractedDateString VARCHAR(256)
    , @convertedDate DATETIME

SET @startIndex = CHARINDEX('(', @rtrail) + 1 -- Add 1 to make it exclude the index character
SET @endIndex = CHARINDEX(')', @rtrail)
SET @dateStringLength = @endIndex - @startIndex
SET @extractedDateString = SUBSTRING(@rtrail, @startIndex, @dateStringLength)
SET @convertedDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @extractedDateString)

-- Display the results
SELECT @startIndex
    , @endIndex
    , @extractedDateString
    , @convertedDate
```

Comment: Thnx for your help. But most of the times it will start with another word what i will do on that time.it will work same for that.